# Jekyll Asset Pipeline + YUI fail to compress JS file

Tags: ruby, yui, jekyll

I'm building a site using Jekyll and [Jekyll Asset Pipeline](https://github.com/matthodan/jekyll-asset-pipeline) and when I generate the site I get the following error:

```
Configuration from /home/liamzebedee/Documents/blog/_config.yml
Building site: /home/liamzebedee/Documents/blog -> /home/liamzebedee/Documents/blog/_site
Asset Pipeline: Processing 'css_asset_tag' manifest 'global'
Asset Pipeline: Saved 'global-209b6871f359105f20dc61685687e480.css' to '/home/liamzebedee/Documents/blog/_site/assets'
Asset Pipeline: Processing 'javascript_asset_tag' manifest 'global'
Asset Pipeline: Failed to compress 'global-31b4b6cd8ed5427ca98bb8f30ce0e75e.js' with 'JekyllAssetPipeline::JavaScriptCompressor'.
Liquid Exception: undefined method `exitstatus' for nil:NilClass in content
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/yui-compressor-0.9.6/lib/yui/compressor.rb:84:in `block in compress'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/yui-compressor-0.9.6/lib/yui/compressor.rb:117:in `streamify'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/yui-compressor-0.9.6/lib/yui/compressor.rb:66:in `compress'
```

I'm really unsure as to what could be causing this. This is my `compress.rb` plugin to facilitate the JS compression using YUI:

```
require 'jekyll_asset_pipeline'

module JekyllAssetPipeline
  class JavaScriptCompressor < JekyllAssetPipeline::Compressor
    require 'yui/compressor'

    def self.filetype
      '.js'
    end

    def compress
      return YUI::JavaScriptCompressor.new(munge: true).compress(@content)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compress method has a typo in the arguments to `new()`, correction below.

```
def compress
  return YUI::JavaScriptCompressor.new(:munge => true).compress(@content)
end
```

I suspect this is an error in the jekyll-asset-pipeline documentation.